# Changing list column width with Script Editor doesn't break line

Tags: sharepoint-server, list, web-part, formatting, script-webpart

I have a webpart that has a list with columns.

To change the width of these columns I inserted a Script Editor and used this code:

```
<style>
.ms-vh-div[displayname='Beschreibung'] {
width: 450px;
}
.ms-vh-div[displayname='Standort'] {
width: 200px;
}
.ms-vh-div[displayname='MaxAnzahlTeilnehmer'] {
width: 100px;
}
</style>
```

The problem ist that the width of the column "Standort" can't be reduced more. 
I want the content of that column to get to the next line, so that I can change the width.

See:

[image: width]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try below nth:child to apply the CSS.

My test demo:

```
<style type="text/css">
        table.ms-listviewtable tr th:nth-child(4) {
            display: block;
            width: 160px !important;
            white-space: pre-wrap;
            word-wrap: break-word;
        }
        table.ms-listviewtable tr td:nth-child(4) {
            display: block;
            width: 160px !important;
            white-space: pre-wrap;
            word-wrap: break-word;
        }
    </style>
```

[image]